# Flink app-level barriers

Tags: apache-flink

I'm trying to figure out what's the proper way to make kind of a barrier on merging multiple streams in Flink.

So let's say I have 4 keyed streams each calculating some aggregated statistics over batches of data. Next I want to combine results of these 4 streams into one stream (Y) and perform some additional computation on received 4 summaries.

[image]

The problem is how to make **Y** node wait until it received all the summaries with X=N before going forward with X=N+1.
In the picture node **3** sent its summary X=N later than node **4** sent its X=N+1
so node **Y** must wait until it has received node **3** summary while caching summaries with X=N+1 from other nodes somehow.

I couldn't find anything similar in documentation so I'd really appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out this task can be solved by simply doing the following:

```
.keyBy(X)
.countWindow(4)
.fold(...)
```